Invalid expression in MS Access
I am using the below query to calculate sum of 5 variables  in another field called Total. But I am getting the below syntax error. I am unable to understand the problem. Can any one take a look. Thank you in advance
IIf(IsNull([One]), 0, [One]) 
+ IIf(IsNull([Two]), 0, [Two]) 
+ IIf(IsNull([Three]), 0, [Three]) 
+ IIf(IsNull([Four]), 0, [Four]) 
+ IIf(IsNull([Five]), 0, [Five])

Syntax Error:
**The expression you entered contains invalid syntax.**
You may have entered an operand without an operator


This works for me in MSAccess 2010 :  SELECT Table1.*, IIf(IsNull([One]),0,[One])+IIf(IsNull([Two]),0,[Two])+IIf(IsNull([Three]),0,[Three])+IIf(IsNull([Four]),0,[Four])+IIf(IsNull([Five]),0,[Five]) AS Total
FROM Table1;

Could you by chance be missing SELECT or FROM keywords?

Given a table named Table1 (with 5 fields named One,Two,Three,Four,Five) a valid query with your formula would be:
SELECT Table1.*, 
     IIf(IsNull([One]),0,[One])+
     IIf(IsNull([Two]),0,[Two])+
     IIf(IsNull([Three]),0,[Three])+
     IIf(IsNull([Four]),0,[Four])+
     IIf(IsNull([Five]),0,[Five]) AS Total 
FROM Table1;




One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Total




1
2
3
4
5
15




Use the NZ function rather than IIF statements.
SELECT NZ(One,0)+NZ(Two,0)+NZ(Three,0)+NZ(Four,0)+NZ(FIve,0) As Total FROM Table1
